# Replacing Images with iframes

Tags: css, image, iframe

I have been asked to replace images with iframe videos. The code given to me appears as a banner on the specific website (https://www.bongenie-grieder.com/). The code I was given is the following:

```
.sliderUn {
    background-image:url('[imagePath]Attachment/Homepage/2020/08/21/HP1-500x580.jpg');
    background-position: center top!important;
}
    
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 
  .sliderUn {
    background-image:url('[imagePath]Attachment/Homepage/2020/08/21/HP1-1000x1160.jpg');
background-position: center top!important;
    

}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .sliderUn {
    background-image:url('[imagePath]Attachment/Homepage/2020/08/21/HP1-500x580.jpg');
    background-position: center top!important;
}
}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 350px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 350px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (min-width: 350px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 350px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 350px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) and (min-width: 350px) { 
  .sliderUn {
    background-image:url('[imagePath]Attachment/Homepage/2020/08/21/HP1-1000x1160.jpg');
    background-position: center top!important;

}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    .sliderUn {
    background-image:url('[imagePath]Attachment/Homepage/2020/08/21/HP1-2000x570.jpg');
    background-position: center top!important;
}
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
     .sliderUn {
        background-image:url('[imagePath]Attachment/Homepage/2020/08/21/HP1-4000x1140.jpg');
background-position: center top!important;
    }
}
    @media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
        .home-slider .home-title {
        max-width: 280px;
        text-align: center;
    }
        .home-sup-title {
            max-width: 280px;
        }
        
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 415px) and (max-width: 1024px){
        .home-slider .home-title {
        max-width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    }
    
    .left_espot .home-slider {
 min-height: 400px;
}
```

Does anyone know how this can be done? I am unfortunately a total noob at coding. Thanks a million for your help!